# Understanding DialogFragment Reference Documentation Basic Dialog Example

Tags: android, android-dialogfragment

I am trying to understand the Basic Dialog example at the beginning of the API Reference for the DialogFragment class.

The last sentence *before* the **Alert Dialog** heading reads:

```
"Note that in this case DialogFragment will take care of popping the transaction
 of the Dialog is dismissed separately from it."
```

I don't understand what this means. It doesn't seem to read as a correctly constructed English sentence (but then again, English grammar was not my best subject back in my school days).

Could anyone who already has a good understanding of the DialogFragment class please either;

```
A) explain what the sentence means.
```

or

```
B) if it is a typo, indicate how it should actually read.
```

Comment: I think you're right. The sentence doesn't really make sense. However I believe what it wants to say is, that the transaction (showing the dialog) will be popped from the back stack automatically, if (not 'of') the dialog is dismissed in whatever way...

(dismiss == pop from backstack)

Comment: @jpm Thanks for the response. If I understand, it's saying we don't need to provide any code ourselves to deal with popping the dialog from the backstack, because the DialogFragment class takes care of this behind the scenes for us already.

Comment: yeah, that's what I assume